# Redirected automatically to a store view based on a user group (B2C & B2B) - M2

Tags: magento2, customer, redirect, store-view, b2b

I have created two store views, one for B2C and one for B2B. I need that when a B2B customer login will be redirected automatically to the view created for their user group. But for B2C customers can use the normal store view. I'm creating a plugin to do this. I created these files in these paths:

**/app/code/MyPlugin/CustomerLogin/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost">
        <plugin name="myPluginCustomerloginLoginpostplugin" type="\MyPlugin\CustomerLogin\Plugin\LoginPostPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**/app/code/MyPlugin/CustomerLogin/Plugin/LoginPostPlugin.php**

```
<?php

namespace MyPlugin\CustomerLogin\Plugin;

class LoginPostPlugin
{
    public function afterExecute(
        \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject,
        $result)
    {
        //-- check group is retail customer or not
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
        if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()){
            $groupId = $customerSession->getCustomerGroupId();
            if ($groupId == 2){
                $result->setPath('?___store=Wholesale&___from_store=Wholesale');
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

And the view changes to the selected view (wholesale), but when I open a product or a category, the view changes to the predefined view, the change does not become effective. Any other idea of being able to make the fixed exchange?

This is the line that I do not know what to put in order that the scope of view remains:

**$result->setPath('?___store=Wholesale&___from_store=Wholesale');**

Any ideas to solve this problem? I need to make a change of store view and keep the change.

Comment: Can someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set store in cookie with specific store code by using below code

```
    protected $_storeRepository;

    protected $_storeCookieManager;

    protected $_storeManagerInterface;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Api\StoreRepositoryInterface $storeRepository,
        \Magento\Store\Api\StoreCookieManagerInterface $StoreCookieManagerInterface,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManagerInterface
    )
    {
        $this->_storeRepository = $storeRepository;
        $this->_storeCookieManager = $StoreCookieManagerInterface;
        $this->_storeManagerInterface = $storeManagerInterface;
    }

    public function afterExecute(
        \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject,
        $result)
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
        if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()){
            $groupId = $customerSession->getCustomerGroupId();
            if ($groupId == 2){
                $storeCode = 'your_store_code1';
            } else {
                $storeCode = 'your_store_code2';
            }
            $store = $this->_storeRepository->getActiveStoreByCode($storeCode);
            $this->_storeCookieManager->setStoreCookie($store);

        }
        return $result;
    }
```

To change store view to default store view use `controller_action_predispatch` in `/app/code/MyPlugin/CustomerLogin/etc/frontend/events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch">
        <observer name="store_switcher" instance="MyPlugin\CustomerLogin\Observer\SwitchStore" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Your `/app/code/MyPlugin\CustomerLogin\Observer\SwitchStore.php` will check the user loggedin or not to change store view.

```
namespace MyPlugin\CustomerLogin\Observer;

class SwitchStore implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

    protected $_storeRepository;

    protected $_storeCookieManager;

    protected $_customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Api\StoreRepositoryInterface $storeRepository,
        \Magento\Store\Api\StoreCookieManagerInterface $StoreCookieManagerInterface,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSession
    )
    {
        $this->_storeRepository = $storeRepository;
        $this->_storeCookieManager = $StoreCookieManagerInterface;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession->create();
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        if (!$this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            $storeCode = 'default_store_code';
            $store = $this->_storeRepository->getActiveStoreByCode($storeCode);
            $this->_storeCookieManager->setStoreCookie($store);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The ID of my store view is 12, what option should I use? $storeCode = '12'; or $storeCode = 12';

Comment: No use your store code..

Comment: The store code is the code that I put when creating the store view? If so, should I use the store code with or without quotes?

Comment: use with quotes....

Comment: So, I have to use this code: $storeCode = 'Wholesale', right?

Comment: Yes...exactly..

Comment: I have to add some more data in my files: di.xml / module.xml / registration.php?

Comment: No just change the plugin file only....`/app/code/MyPlugin/CustomerLogin/Plugin/LoginPostPlugin.php`

Comment: ok! Thank you, I'm going to try it and I'll tell you if it works or not. Thank you again! I need to make the change and keep it, if your solution works I will be very grateful! :)

Comment: Works!!! Thank you so much for your solution! The change of the store view is maintained :)

Comment: Welcome ......:-)

Comment: How can I make the store view to return to the default store view when the customer log out?

Comment: Will update the answer shortly

Comment: Thanks for the update! It works very well! :)

Comment: I have special prices for the group of users I am using, groupId = 2 (which is the one I have assigned the store view) but with your solution I do not see the special price for this group of users, Could you help me solve this problem?

Comment: But you didn't mention anything that is related with special price in your question.....Can you pls elaborate? better create new question.

Comment: There is detailed information about special pricing for customer groups - https://www.customerparadigm.com/how-to-set-group-pricing-in-magento-2/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94534/discussion-between-despotars-and-ranganathan).

Comment: Is it possible that when we create the cookie for the store (with the plugin), we lose the configuration to see the special prices for this customer group?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94538/discussion-on-answer-by-ranganathan-redirected-automatically-to-a-store-view-bas).

Comment: I was doing tests, and in my shop in the production environment the special prices for the group of users Wholesale always shows the correct prices. In the development environment (where I have the plugin with its code for the automatic change of store view) the special prices are not shown correctly (as we have checked together). I believe that the problem is that when creating the cookie, it is necessary to add that the user is from the group of Wholesale users so that you always keep in mind that the prices must be special for this group? Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: i'm sorry will explore about it and let you know

Comment: No problem! but, do you think that this could be the mistake I have? That should be included in the cookie in any way by the group to which the user belongs so that magento will always take it into account and not from time to time?

Comment: Not sure, just disable this plugin and manually change store code to check the issue occur or not

Comment: I have uninstall the plugin, and now everything works fine. You can check it with the URL of the store and the user I sent you. Can you see that without the plugin everything works correctly?? (the products are shown with the prices correctly always in the store view Wholesale if you log in with the user Wholesale)

Comment: Ohh,,,,,now the problem with above code

Comment: I have detected that now that I do not have the extension installed, everything works fine but if I change store view manually, the special prices for this group of clients are lost. So, the problem is in magento?

Comment: This code is for changing store view. But if I wanted to make a store change, how would the code be?

Comment: You can use this code to switch the specific store with the id of default store view which you want to switch.......Every store has at least 1 store view right..~

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it will redirect to specific store view but when you click any page it will redirect to a default store page. because you set only redirect path not set store, so once go to another page it will redirect to default store.

You need to also set **store** as well. once the store is set it will affect the whole page.

You can set the store using below way.

Inject **StoreManagerInterface** in cunstruct.

```
<?php
namespace MyPlugin\CustomerLogin\Plugin;

class LoginPostPlugin
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManagerInterface;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManagerInterface
    ) {
        $this->_storeManagerInterface = $storeManagerInterface;
    }


    public function afterExecute(
        \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject,
        $result)
    {
        //-- check group is retail customer or not
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
        if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()){
            $groupId = $customerSession->getCustomerGroupId();
            if ($groupId == 2){
                $this->_storeManagerInterface->setCurrentStore(1);
                $result->setPath('?___store=Wholesale&___from_store=Wholesale');
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

I hope it helps! Thanks.

Comment: What number should I put here? $this->_storeManagerInterface->setCurrentStore(1);

Comment: `store=Wholesale` storeId

Comment: for this: $result->setPath('?___store=Wholesale&___from_store=Wholesale'); Is it possible to do something so that this data does not appear in the URL?

Comment: Hi @chirag-patel, I used the code that you showed me, that put the ID of the store view that I want to show, but it does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: You can remove `?___store=Wholesale&___from_store=Wholesale` this from system config Go to `Store > config > general > web > URL option > Add Store Code to Urls` set to `NO`

Comment: For example `store=Wholesale` is your store and check what is storeID of that store ain admin > store. then set that id to function `$this->_storeManagerInterface->setCurrentStore(1);` so it will set `store=Wholesale`  for whole site.

Comment: I opened my store view and in the URL I can see the store_id and the number is 12, is this number?

Comment: There is a simple logic you have created 2 store view 1) B2C = genaral 2) B2B = wholesale. Now you want to redirect a wholesale customer to B2B so you have to set the second store (B2B) for that customer using `setCurrentStore(2)` nothing else. I think you are confused.

Comment: Many thanks, It works properly when the wholesale access to the site, but, when he interacts with the page, the store view changes to B2C: prices are still correct for B2B but not the view of the page or the dropdown menu. For example, the logo that appears is the one a I have set for B2C and not the correct one. Do you know what I mean and how to fix it? Many thanks for your help

Comment: If your issue is resolved and my answer is useful to you. then you can accept an answer so it will useful to another user.

And for your store logo, you can set your store logo from `Admin > content > design > configuration` Edit store which one you have to set logo. that's it!

Comment: I have set a logo for the B2B store view and when the user logs in he can see the logo for the B2B store, but when he opens a product or a category, the logo of the B2C store appears again, this is what What I mean is that you do not keep changing the store view. If you want by private I can show you the web so you can see the problem and help me solve it, right?

Comment: Any ideas on how to solve my problem with the store views?

Comment: I have detected that the prices were maintained because a module that I bought was activated so that wholesale customers did not pay taxes. This is not right because wholesale customers must pay taxes. I changed this rule and now it happens the same as with the logo. When doing log in, the prices and the logo (from the B2B store view) appear correctly, but when you open a product or a category, the prices and the logo change back to the B2C store configuration

Comment: Could you help me please?

Comment: It's not working, you can check on the web. Can you please help me or tell me if you will help me or not to seek help from another side? I want to give you 50 points, I would even give you 100 points more if necessary, please help me!

Comment: Could you help me please?

Comment: I try my best. if I found something I will let you know.

Comment: If you go on the web, you can see the drop down that you asked me to see. Do you think you can find a solution?

Comment: If you find a solution today or tomorrow, I could give you 150 extra points creating another question and you answer it, do you think it's okay for you?

Comment: Ok, dude. it's not all about points, don't worry if I found something I get back to you. but you have to also try :)

Comment: Of course!! I'm trying to find a solution but it's not easy for me because I am not an expert in PHP development but I'm working on it! Thank you friend, I hope to see your answer soon! :)